# Particle system does not get updated in aframe

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create a simulation for an X-Ray Tube, where you can change the current or voltage and see the effects on the electrones and photons. 
I've setup the electrones as a particle system with the aframe-particle-system-component. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-particle-system-component/v/1.1.3) Now I'm trying to change the particle system with a slider.
The problem is that the input of the slider gets registered, but it has no effect on the particle system in the scene.

The weird thing for me is, that the particle system will get changed, when I call the setAttribute() function outside of the EventListener. But than it changes only once at the beginning obviously, which does not help me.

The DOM of the entity does get updated and shows the new value of the size, when i inspect it in the console. Even the aframe inspector shows the updated size. But the actual particle system in the scene still shows the size, that i set in the html file.

Here is the js code that I'm using for this:

```
var elektron = document.querySelector('#ParticleSystem');
var scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');

//Var for the two sliders
var rangeCurrent = document.querySelector('#rangeCurrent');
var rangeVoltage = document.querySelector('#rangeVoltage');

var current = rangeCurrent.value;
var voltage = rangeVoltage.value;

//EventListener for the slider
rangeCurrent.addEventListener('change', function(){
  current = rangeCurrent.value;
  elektron.setAttribute('particle-system', {size: current});
});
```

There are no error messages.

I've been stuck with this problem the whole day and would be really thankful if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work!!
In the update() function of the particle-system-component script they don't initiate the new ParticleSystem with the new data you define with setAttribute. I tried to fix it by myself for a while but couldn't get it to work. So then I used the earlier version 1.12 of the particle-system-component and now it works.